# Как узнать название класса текущего элемента? в Android Studio

Tags: android

У меня есть чужой код и разбираться со всем нет времени, да и по просту не хватит его. Слишком большой проект.

Как мне узнать класс который отвечает за нажатие в приложении Button.

Можно ли как - то сделать так, чтобы запустить приложение, нажать на кнопку, и в это время в Android Studio где - то укажется название класса или layout файла, или какую - нибудь отсылку на исходник.....

P.S. Речь сейчас идет НЕ ПРО! Debug и BreakPoint. Потому что я не знаю куда BreakPoint ставить. А без BreakPoint Debug работать не будет.

Comment: Ну единственное что приходит в голову запустить espresso тесты) там по нажатию на кнопки сможете опрелить layout где они находятся.

Comment: @Morozov, А разве нельзя в Debug выделить все BreakPoint? типо OnClick? Если можно то как не подскажите

Comment: не подскажу, да и думаю всё же для вас будет куда проще пройтись по приложению следующим образом Run - Record Espresso Test - и для нужных вам кнопок делайте Add assertion.

Comment: @Morozov, Забыл как называется. В презентации гугла была показана такая штука. В приложении пишешь текст или нажимаешь, а слева отображается вводимй текст, название компонеты и т.д.

Comment: не совсем понимаю о чём вы, вы про find usage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У кнопки должен быть указан id, попробуйте найти его упоминание в проекте